# Validating the child's age against the parents age in xsd

Tags: xml, xsd

I have an xml like below

```
<parents>
  <mother name="MMM" age="55" />
  <children>
      <child name="CCC" gender="male" age="25" />
  </children>
</parents>
```

To validate mother's age or Child's age we can write the xsd like below

```
<xs:element name="mother">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:attribute name="name" type="xs:string"/>
        <xs:attribute name="age">
            <xs:simpleType>
                <xs:restriction base="xs:integer">
                <xs:minInclusive value="0"/>
                <xs:maxInclusive value="120"/>
                </xs:restriction>
            </xs:simpleType>
        </xs:attribute>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

But If I want to validate the child's age, which should not be more than mother's age?

Comment: What you are referring to is known as [Co-occurrence constraints](http://books.xmlschemata.org/relaxng/relax-CHP-7-SECT-2.html). And it is not possible with XML 1.0. You should look into RelaxNG and XML 1.1.

Answer (score 1):

From [Wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML_Schema_%28W3C%29):

> XSD provides no facilities to state that the value or presence of one
>   attribute is dependent on the values or presence of other attributes
>   (so-called co-occurrence constraints).

And that's exactly what you want: restrict the value of child's age based on value of mother's age. So it's not possible to do with XML Schema 1.0, unfortunately.

It's possible to do with XML Schema 1.1, though, by something like this (very rough example, just to show the concept):

```
<xs:assert test="@age < ../../mother[@age]"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

as far as i know, you can't do this with regular xsd restrictions. you'd have to use something like schematron to build this in.

Answer (score 0):

I've not used XSD for quite some time but one of the things I remember using were functions that you could add.

This page should give you some tips, it's a bit ugly in its presentation but should give you a start.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc302079.aspx

This link is also quite good.

http://our.umbraco.org/wiki/reference/xslt/extend-your-xslt-with-custom-functions

Answer (score 0):

Use XSD 1.1 with assertions. XSD 1.1 is currently implemented in Saxon and Xerces.